# GCP Stackdriver Monitoring billing with no ingested metrics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, billing, google-cloud-stackdriver

I would like to understand the Stackdriver Monitoring billing.

I'd enabled the Stackdriver Monitoring API for one of my projects but I forgot to disable it. The project has no ingested metrics in the last month, but I was billed anyway.

Can you guys help me to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Where are the details about what you were billed? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Is your question off-topic? https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use Billing Cloud Support, they have a Chat service and you will be able to speak almost immediately to someone who will be able to check everything in your infrastructure and explain to you the billing charge, and if there is some issue they will help :). 
You can contact them in here: [1]

It will redirect to your Google Console and from there you will have to click in "Chat".

Regards.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/billing